# Hartshorne chapter 2 exercise $2.17$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> Let $f: X \to Y$ be a morphism of schemes, and suppose that $Y$ can be covered
> by open subsets $U_i$, such that for each $i$, the induced map $f^{-1}(U_i) \to U_i$ is an
> isomorphism. Then $f$ is an isomorphism.

I can show that $f$ is injective and surjective as follows. Suppose $f(x) = f(y)$, then  as $U_i$'s cover $Y$, there exists $U_i$ such that $f(x),f(y) \in U_i$ and since $f^{-1}(U_i) \to U_i$ is injective $x=y$.

Also $f$ is surjective since for any $y \in Y$ there is an $U_i$ such that $f^{-1}(U_i)$ contains $x$ that maps to $y$.

I think I still need to show that $f$ is continuous, has a continuous inverse and that the map $f^\sharp$ on sheaves is also a ring isomorhpism. How can I proceed with this?

---

I think I have a proof for this. Let $g_i : U_i \to f^{-1}(U_i)$ be the inverses of the given isomorphisms. Now if we can show that $g_i$ and $g_j$ agree on $U_i \cap U_j$ we can glue them to form an inverse for $f$.

Now this follows since $f |_{f^{-1}(U_i) \cap f^{-1}(U_j)} \circ g_i|_{U_i \cap U_j} = f |_{f^{-1}(U_i) \cap f^{-1}(U_j)} \circ g_j|_{U_i \cap U_j}$ as both give the identity.

Comment: Hint: for $f^\#$, think stalks.

Comment: I think this can be done without considering stalks? @TabesBridges

Answer (score 2):

You have to check two things:

1. the map of topological spaces given by $f$ is a homeomorphism
2. after the first item, you need to verify that the map of sheaves $\mathcal{O}_Y\to f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ is an isomorphism.

For the first item, try proving the following more general lemma:

> Given a map of topological spaces $f:X\to Y$ and an open cover $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ of $Y$ such that $f|_{f^{-1}(U_i)}: f^{-1}(U_i)\to U_i$ is a homeomorphism for each $i\in I$, $f$ is a homeomorphism.

A few hints about this: use the hypotheses to verify that $f$ is a bijection. Therefore, it has a well-defined inverse map $f^{-1}$ (no gluing needed). You can verify continuity of $f^{-1}$ by observing that continuity can be checked locally, and the open cover condition tells you that $f^{-1}$ is continuous on an open cover.

For the second item, note that given a morphism of sheaves $\psi:\mathcal{F}\to \mathcal{G}$ on a space $Y$, the property of $\psi$ being an isomorphism can be checked on an open cover. Given the setup, we know that there exists an open cover $\{U_i\}$ of $Y$ such that $f|_{f^{-1}(U_i)}:f^{-1}(U_i)\to U_i$ is an isomorphism of *schemes*. In particular, the induced morphism $f^{\#}|_{U_i}: \mathcal{O}_{U_i}\to f_*\mathcal{O}_{f^{-1}(U_i)}$ is an isomorphism of sheaves. Item 2. follows.